# May I ask for a little clarification on subjunctive and bare infinitive?

Tags: subjunctive-mood, bare-infinitive

I have just finished reading an extremely long thread on the above mentioned subjects on this site: (https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/demand-request-suggest-that-bare-infinitive-subjunctive-indicative.384237/)

Although a lot of things cleared up to me, I still have a little confusion about these two sentences :

I'd rather that he be on time. 
I'd rather he was on time.

I found the first one among the examples of a native answerer but i was taught in school that if there's a subject in a "i'd rather-type-sentence" i should use past tense. 
So now i'm a bit puzzled...are they maybe different  because of using "that" one time and not using it the other time?

Thank you all in advance,
Mate

Comment: @Toothrot Me, I’d rather he were on time. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Collins Cobuild English Usage* (p567) states:

> You can use **would rather** followed by a clause to say that you
> would prefer something to happen or to be done. In the clause you use
> the past simple tense.
>
> - *Would* you *rather* she *came* to see me?
> - May I go? - I *'d* rather you *didn't*.

*Practical English Usage* (p492) has a rather more nuanced entry:

> We can use *would rather* to say that a person would prefer somebody
> to do something. We use a special structure with a past tense.
>
> would rather + subject + past tense
>
> - I *'d rather you went* home now.
> - Tomorrow's difficult. I *'d rather you came* next weekend.
> - My wife *would rather we didn't* see each other anymore.
> - Shall I open a window? - I *'d rather you didn't*.
>
> A present tense or present subjunctive is possible e.g. (*I'd rather
> he goes / he go home now*), but unusual.

As a British English native speaker I am unlikely to say *I'd rather that he be on time*. But some American English speakers in particular may prefer it to its past tense alternative.

The presence or absence of *that* makes no difference here.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! You're just great!

Comment: I don't know I’d use *be* there myself, but I might well use *were*.